# nextjs getInitialProps getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

I have an scenario whether I want to get benefit of calling *getInitialProps* (async call executed from server or client side), but I need to store the result of that query in the State of a React component instead of a class.

What I have tried is to call first *getInitialProps* and then call *getDerivedStateFromProps* to store in the state the data that was injected in the Intial props function call.

Can this be a bad practice or lead to some issues when running server side rendering?

Sample:

```
static async getInitialProps() {    
  const data = await getUserCollection();

  return {
    userCollection: data,  
  }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.userCollection !== prevState.myStateCollection) {
    return ({
      myStateCollection: nextProps.userCollection,
    })
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

State and Props definitions (typescript):

```
interface Props {
  userCollection: UserEntity[],
}

interface State {
  myStateCollection : UserEntity[];
}
```

Comment: I would use the `shouldComponentUpdate` for props comparison without doing it in every method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but the overall approach is the right one to inject data in the state from getInitalProps or there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think is the right method. But React developers recommend some alternatives. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html